# psql changing comma to decimal for importing CSV file

Tags: postgis, postgresql, csv, database

I try to import a CSV file into a PostgreSQL database that runs on a remote server.
I use psql via SSH.

```
AIS_DB=# CREATE TABLE bet_srk_2008 (
AIS_DB(# Unique_VesselTraject numeric,
AIS_DB(# AISTrajectPositionTimestampLocal timestamp,
AIS_DB(# RandomVesselAISKey varchar,
AIS_DB(# AISTrajectPositionSpeedOverGround varchar,
AIS_DB(# AISTrajectPositionCourseOverGround varchar,
AIS_DB(# VesselAISLength varchar,
AIS_DB(# VesselAISBeam varchar,
AIS_DB(# VesselAISMaximumDraught varchar,
AIS_DB(# VesselTypeAISDescription varchar,
AIS_DB(# BOZ varchar,
AIS_DB(# AISTrajectPositionLatitude numeric,
AIS_DB(# AISTrajectPositionLongitude numeric,
AIS_DB(# TrajectAISDestination varchar
AIS_DB(# );
```

CREATE TABLE

```
AIS_DB=# \COPY bet_srk_2008 FROM '/home/thecaptain/Export2008.csv' DELIMITERS ';'CSV HEADER;
```

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "51,2628135681152"
CONTEXT:  COPY bet_srk_2008, line 2, column aistrajectpositionlatitude: "51,2628135681152"

I think the problem is that the data uses a comma instead of point as a decimal. Is there a way to circumvent this in the import process?
The datasets have 100 million+ lines and a find and replace is making nano run out of memory.
If I use VARCHAR instead of NUMERIC it won't let me ST_MAKEPOINT it to the geom column.

This is the whole text:

```
CREATE TABLE bet_srk_2008 (
Unique_VesselTraject numeric,
AISTrajectPositionTimestampLocal timestamp,
RandomVesselAISKey varchar,
AISTrajectPositionSpeedOverGround varchar,
AISTrajectPositionCourseOverGround varchar,
VesselAISLength varchar,
VesselAISBeam varchar,
VesselAISMaximumDraught varchar,
VesselTypeAISDescription varchar,
BOZ varchar,
AISTrajectPositionLatitude numeric,
AISTrajectPositionLongitude numeric,
TrajectAISDestination varchar
);

\COPY bet_srk_2008 FROM '/home/thecaptain/Export2008.csv' DELIMITERS 
';'CSV HEADER;

ALTER TABLE bet_srk_2008 ADD COLUMN geom geometry (POINT, 4326 );

UPDATE bet_srk_2008 SET geom 
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(AISTrajectPositionLongitude, 
AISTrajectPositionLatitude) ,4326);

CREATE INDEX bet_srk_2008_index ON bet_srk_2008 USING GIST ( geom );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution for anybody that has the same problem.
I am still interested if somebody has a solution without having to alter the dataset prior to importing.

I use Linux as a operating system on desktop and servers.
I changed the comma to point:

```
sed -i 's/,/./g' Export2008.csv
```

Comment: Note that you should be able to `\COPY bet_srk_2008 FROM PROGRAM 'sed -i 's/,/./g' Export2008.csv';`. Alternatively, you can *a)* setup a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to `REPLACE(NEW."AISTrajectPositionLongitude", ',', '.')`, (for both columns, of course) or *b)* run that same string replace (and a cast to `FLOAT`) in your `UPDATE` statement within `ST_MakePoint`. The trigger would likely be the least performant option, and using *sed* the fastest, but that's only an educated guess.

Comment: @geozelot the trigger or the cast would work if the lat/long columns were Text.

Comment: Another option, if you can replace the `,` before (for example if you have a text and don't want to remove all commas from it), is to load the csv to a temp table, then to load your table by reading/converting from the temp table.

Comment: @JGH since CSV input is text *per se*, and `xx,yyy` no valid format, I assumed that as given (also I didn't read the table definitions...).

Comment: And yet another option would be to have a `VIEW` with all columns defined as `TEXT` and an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that inserts cast values into the actual table. But in any case, I'd go for the piped input from `sed`...